# Storing data associated with opened file in linux kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to observe some operations performed on files (and do it from kernel level). I have to attach some data to opened file descriptor (for instance a single int value). More precisely, for each opened file in `sys_do_open` I decide whether to track the file or not. For further usage I have to store somewhere this decision.

There is a field `private_data` in `struct file`, it seems to be good enough for my needs, but I suppose it's used also by other modules.

So, how can I store some data associated with opened file descriptor (for every opened file)?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `my_private_data`.

Comment: @CL. Splendid, brilliant, easy, smart :)